# Is there a way to get all values level by all level in a Pandas MultiIndex?

Tags: pandas

**input**

```
idx = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([['A', 'B'], ['C', 'D']])
```

`idx`

```
MultiIndex([('A', 'C'),
            ('A', 'D'),
            ('B', 'C'),
            ('B', 'D')],
           )
```

**desired output:**

like **[level0 values, level1 values]** (values can be Index or list and so on..)

**desired output of input:**

```
[['A', 'A', 'B', 'B'], ['C', 'D', 'C', 'D']]
```

my try1:

```
>>> idx.to_frame().T.values.tolist()

[['A', 'A', 'B', 'B'], ['C', 'D', 'C', 'D']]
```

my try2:

```
>>> [idx.get_level_values(i) for i in range(len(idx[0]))]

[Index(['A', 'A', 'B', 'B'], dtype='object'),
 Index(['C', 'D', 'C', 'D'], dtype='object')]
```

**Both of my attempts satisfy the desired result.**

**However, is there a function that can execute this? Or is there a simpler way?**

Answer (score 2):

`idx.get_level_values` seems to be the fastest.

However, since MultiIndexes are iterables, an easy way would be to use [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip):

```
out = list(zip(*idx))
```

Output: `[('A', 'A', 'B', 'B'), ('C', 'D', 'C', 'D')]`

As lists:

```
out = list(map(list, zip(*idx)))
# [['A', 'A', 'B', 'B'], ['C', 'D', 'C', 'D']]
```

##### timings

Tested on 20 levels, ~1M rows:

```
# list(zip(*idx))
733 ms ± 17.6 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

# [idx.get_level_values(i) for i in range(len(idx[0]))]
175 ms ± 3.59 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)

# list(map(idx.get_level_values, range(idx.nlevels)))
175 ms ± 969 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)

# [[x for x in idx.get_level_values(level)] for level in range(idx.nlevels)]
1.15 s ± 15.1 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

# [idx.get_level_values(level).tolist() for level in range(idx.nlevels)]
276 ms ± 5.42 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

Comment: i expect `index.get_level_values` to be faster ?

Comment: @sammywemmy indeed, I added timings

Comment: @mozway: it would be interesting to see what is the impact on performance of converting the result of your second solution from index to list. Moreover, it would be interesting to check how are all methods comparable when the problem size is small or moderate.

Comment: @PaulS I added the conversion to list. Timing on tiny inputs doesn't really make sense (unless you repeat an operation on a lot of tiny inputs, but in this case there are so many possible sources of overhead that this should be clearly stated as an objective).

Comment: Thanks, @mozway! I am always a bit skeptical about performance gains of microseconds, since, as programmers, we can get easily distracted from more important issues. Moreover, through time, the performance outlook may change because of improvements in the algorithms underlying Python and Pandas. And from year to year, the machines increase a lot their performance, that makes obsolete many past performance issues.

Answer (score 1):

Another possible solution:

```
[[x for x in idx.get_level_values(level)] for level in range(idx.nlevels)]
```

Output:

```
[['A', 'A', 'B', 'B'], ['C', 'D', 'C', 'D']]
```

Comment: I wouldn't add the inner comprehension, that would decrease a lot efficiency

Comment: Thanks, @mozway, for commenting my solution. I have timed your solution and mine and got the following results: mine: `36.3 µs ± 1.26 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10,000 loops each)`; yours (with conversion from `index` to `list`: `47.1 µs ± 1.4 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10,000 loops each)`.

Comment: You have to time on a larger input to see meaningful differences. My point was that if you want to convert to lists `[idx.get_level_values(level).tolist() for level in range(idx.nlevels)]` would be more appropriate than a list comprehension.

Answer (score 0):

idx.get_level_values seems to be the fastest.

However, since MultiIndexes are iterables, an easy way would be to use zip:

out = list(zip(*idx))
Output: [('A', 'A', 'B', 'B'), ('C', 'D', 'C', 'D')]

As lists:

out = list(map(list, zip(*idx)))

## [['A', 'A', 'B', 'B'], ['C', 'D', 'C', 'D']]

Comment: looks like a copy of my answer, is this a copy/paste error?

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).